# How to view options tkernel module was loaded with?

Tags: linux, kernel-module, parameters, modprobe

How could one view options/parameters that were passed to kernel when loading it?

`modinfo -p <modulename>`

doesn't fit for this problem as it displays it seems all available parameters.

Linux 4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/sys/module/<name>/parameters`:

```
$ tree /sys/module/*/parameters
/sys/module/8250/parameters
├── nr_uarts
├── probe_rsa
├── share_irqs
└── skip_txen_test
/sys/module/acpiphp/parameters
└── disable
/sys/module/ahci/parameters
└── marvell_enable
/sys/module/amdgpu/parameters
├── aspm
├── audio
├── bapm
...
```